# Java Rule-based Systems

Tags: java, rule-engine, expert-system

Which library should I use in developing a rule-based system with following rules? :

The input would an exam of a student

```
if No. 1 question is wrong
     then student should study this part of the syllabus
```

the other part of the rule is like this

```
if x got score <= a specific scope
     then knowledge level is y
else if x got score >= a specific scope:
     then knowledge level is z
```

I'm going to develop the system in Java, JSP and servlets.

I thinking of using [JESS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jess_%28programming_language%29) but I decided to consult to you all, with a better knowledge with this.

And if I'm wrong with my terms, please correct me.

Comment: SO isn't the best place to ask about recommendations

Comment: @MadProgrammer Where do you suggest i go to ask about recommendations?

Comment: You could try [Programmers Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks i'll try asking there